# After symlinking a file, how do I get the path of the original file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, symlink

I have a Ruby script with path `/foo/bar/gazook/script.rb`. I also created a symlink to it in `$HOME/bin`.

Now, I want my Ruby script to access some other file in directory `/foo`, and to keep paths relative, I have a variable `FOO_DIRECTORY = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../../")` in my script.

The problem is that if I run my script from its symlink, this relative directory is wrong (since I guess its expanding from a different location).

How do I fix this? Is there a way besides using an absolute path?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [`File.readlink`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-readlink) to resolve a symlink but you'll want to check [`File.symlink?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/File.html#method-c-symlink-3F) first.

```
path = File.symlink?(__FILE__) ? File.readlink(__FILE__) : __FILE__
```

Then you can work with `path` instead of `__FILE__`. You might want to use `$0` instead of `__FILE__` as well, `__FILE__` is the current filename whereas `$0` is the name of the current script.

Comment: For a more general solution, you need to resolve symlinks in a loop, because one symlink may point to another. Plus, you have to check each and every part of the path: `bin` may be a symlink, too. I'd recommend `File.realpath`.

Answer (score 7):

To get any path relative to the location of your script, *always* use `__dir__`.

`__dir__` is a concise way of saying `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))`. It's available in Ruby >= 2.0. [On `__dir__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190700/why-is-file-uppercase-and-dir-lowercase).

`File.realpath(__FILE__)` (or `Pathname#realpath`) has three advantages compared to `File.readlink`:

- It expands symlinks *anywhere* in the path. `readlink` only expands paths that are the last part of the argument.
- It (recursively) resolves symlinks to symlinks to... `readlink` resolves only the first level.
- You do not have to check whether `path` is a symlink at all. Thus you can drop the `if File.symlink?`.

Consequently it would be good to use `FOO_DIRECTORY = File.join(__dir__, '..', '..')` or `FOO_DIRECTORY = File.dirname(File.dirname(__dir__))`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
require 'pathname'
p File.dirname(Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
FOO_DIRECTORY = File.expand_path("../../../", __FILE__)
```

I's say the problem is that your symlink file is interpreting `File.dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: `expand_path` doesn't resolve symlinks and specify the `dir_string` won't help: ["Relative paths are referenced from the current working directory of the process unless dir_string is given, in which case it will be used as the starting point."](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-expand_path). Furthermore, the second argument to `expand_path` should be a *directory*, not a file name.

Comment: OK, I created a test file, a symlink in my ~/bin directory, and when running the symlink, I get "/home". So I apologize, my solution does not work :(

Comment: And also notice that `File.expand_path("..", __FILE__)` is just a funny way of saying `File.dirname(__FILE__)`.