# Why is __FILE__ uppercase and __dir__ lowercase?

Tags: ruby, syntax, language-implementation

In Ruby 2.0.0-p0, the `__dir__` variable was introduced for easy access to the directory of the file currently being executed.

Why is `__dir__` lowercase when `__FILE__` is uppercase?

Comment: `__FILE__` is constant and `__dir__` is method: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.core/52295

Comment: ```__FILE__``` is not a constant. According to ```Kernel.const_get``` it is not even a valid name for a constant.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I think that is because `__FILE__` is a parse-time constant whereas `__dir__` is a function and returns `File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))`

For more details, see [This discussion](https://web.archive.org/web/20100414044710/http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193674)

Comment: This is one of the very few things about ruby that I find irritating. Oh well.

Comment: The link is outdated.

Answer (score 38):

### TL; DR

The relative merits of language implementation choices are outside the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow question. However, this is a good question because it identifies a potentially confusing use case in the language and seeks to clarify the distinction between the two language elements.

### Keywords, Methods, and Keywords That Look Like Methods

#### `__FILE__` is a Keyword

In Ruby 1.9, `__FILE__` is a keyword. Even though it looks like a method defined on the Object class, the source for [Object#__FILE__](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__) says:

```
# File keywords.rb, line 68
def __FILE__
end
```

A quick scan of the source in 2.0.0-p0 didn't turn up a keywords.rb file, but one assumes that `__FILE__` syntactically remains a keyword. Perhaps someone else can point you to the location of the current definition.

#### `__dir__` is a Method

[Kernel#__dir__](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) is actually a method. You can see this for yourself by grepping the Kernel's defined methods:

```
Kernel.methods.grep /__dir__/
# => [:__dir__]
```

### Bugs and Discussions

The fact that `__FILE__` is both a keyword and (sort of) a method is [called out in a bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7975) and some [bug-related commentary](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7975#note-3). There was also discussion of the various pros and cons of the naming convention in the [Ruby-Core Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20100414044710/http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/193674).

While the answer may be a bit unsatisfactory, that's the current state of affairs. If it's a language design issue you feel strongly about, getting involved with the Ruby core team would be the proper way to address it.

Comment: The keywords table is defined in [defs/keywords](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/defs/keywords#L13) (and interestingly, hasn't changed for four years)