# Opening relative paths from gem

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a simple gem that can load from and save data to text files and zip archives. So, it has four methods: `load_from_file`, `load_from_zip`, `save_to_file` and `save_to_zip` respectfully. The problem is that I can't figure out how to specify relative paths for loading and saving for these methods. Here they go:

```
def load_from_file(filename)
  File.open(filename) do |f|
    f.each { |line| add(line) } # `add` is my another class method
  end
end

def load_from_zip(filename)
  Zip::File.open("#{filename}.zip") do |zipfile|
    zipfile.each { |entry| read_zipped_file(zipfile, entry) } # my private method
  end
end

def save_to_file(filename)
  File.write("#{filename}.txt", data)
end

def save_to_zip(filename)
  Zip::File.open("#{filename}.zip", Zip::File::CREATE) do |zipfile|
    zipfile.get_output_stream('output.txt') { |f| f.print data }
  end
end

private

def read_zipped_file(zipfile, entry)
  zipfile.read(entry).lines.each { |line| add(line) }
end
```

So what I want basically is to allow this gem to load and save files by relative paths whereever it is used in system, e.g. I have an app located in `/home/user/my_app` with two files - `app.rb` and `data.txt`, and I could be able to read the file from this directory without specifying absolute path.

Example:

```
# app.rb
require 'my_gem'

my_gem = MyGem.new
my_gem.load_from_file('data.txt')
```

(Sorry for bad English)

**UPD:** This is not Rails gem and I'm not using Rails. All this is only pure Ruby.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

If I understand it correctly, you don't need to change anything.

Inside `app.rb` and your `gem`, relative paths will be understood relatively to `Dir.pwd`.

If you run `ruby app.rb` from inside `/home/user/my_app` :

- `Dir.pwd` will be `/home/user/my_app`
- both `app.rb` and `my_gem` will look for `'data.txt'` inside `/home/user/my_app`.

## Useful methods, just in case

#### Dir.chdir

If for some reason `Dir.pwd` isn't the desired folder, you could [change directory](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) :

```
Dir.chdir('/home/user/my_app') do
  # relative paths will be based from /home/user/my_app
  # call your gem from here
end
```

#### Get the directory of current file :

[`__dir__`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__dir__) will help you get the directory :

> Returns the canonicalized absolute path of the directory of the file
>   from which this method is called.

#### Get the current file :

`__FILE__` will return the current file. (Note : [uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190700/why-is-file-uppercase-and-dir-lowercase).)

#### Concatenate file paths :

If you need to concatenate file paths, use [`File.expand_path`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-expand_path) or [`File.join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/File.html#method-c-join). Please don't concatenate strings.

If you don't trust that the relative path will be correctly resolved, you could send an absolute path to your method :

```
my_gem.load_from_file(File.expand_path('data.txt'))
```